# Radix Scrypto: How to send Bucket or BucketRef through resim

Tags: smartcontracts, scrypto

I created a blueprint with a method accepting a Bucket and a BucketRef and I don't know how to call it with resim. How can I send buckets when calling a method of my components ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send Buckets (or BucketRefs) to method/functions with `resim` by using the following format: `[amount],[token_resource_def]`.

For example, if your component have the following method:

```
pub fn show_amount(&self, tokens: BucketRef) {
    info!("{}", list.amount());
    list.drop();
}
```

To create a BucketRef of 1000 XRD and send it to this method, you would use `resim` like this:

```
resim call-method [component_address] show_amount 1000,030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004
```